# Adding web part to person.aspx - WebPartId?

Tags: web-part, my-site, my-profile, aspx, personalization

I'm kind of stuck adding a web part to the Person.aspx page....I have a custom web part which I have uploaded but I'm not sure how to add it.

On the masterpage (in SharePoint Designer) I went to Insert->Web Part-> and insterted my web part.

Now in the Person.aspx I copied and pasted this code under one of the web part zones, right now its sitting just as a duplicate of the AskMeAboutWebPart:

```
<SPSWC:AskMeAboutWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{EAC6834A-8E73-4D1B-B7BE-193CBDB09F30}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>My Custom Web Part</Title>
  <FrameType>TitleBarOnly</FrameType>
  <Description>The web part that shows custom things.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>MiddleLeftZone</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge />
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_eac6834a_8e73_4d1b_b7be_193cbdb09f30</ID>
</WebPart>
</SPSWC:AskMeAboutWebPart>
```

Now what do I need to change in this section of code to add my web part? Basically I think I need to change the , the name, and the WebPartId but I'm not sure where to find these things, well other than the name. Where can I find the WebPartId and ??? Would this work for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks you for any assistance

Comment: Why dont you add it programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you add it programmatically, then save master page as a template never done it myself but worth a go.

for adding it to the page programmatically all you need is webpart's dll and here's the tutorial for it

[Add-Web-Part-to-Page-Programmatically.](http://www.keirgordon.com/post/Add-Web-Part-to-Page-Programmatically.aspx)

or try SharePoint Designer

[enter link description here](http://helpmetocode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/add-web-part-inside-master-page-in.html)